# Google App Engine + Form Validation

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, checkbox, radiobuttonlist

I would like to do google app engine form validation but I dont know how to do it?
I tried like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms
from django import newforms as forms


class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
    occupations_choices = (
    ('1', ""),
    ('2', "Undergraduate student"),
    ('3', "Postgraduate student (MSc)"),
    ('4', "Postgraduate student (PhD)"),
    ('5', "Lab assistant"),
    ('6', "Technician"),
    ('7', "Lecturer"),
    ('8', "Other" )
    )

howreach_choices = (
    ('1', ""),        
    ('2', "Typed the URL directly"),
    ('3', "Site is bookmarked"),
    ('4', "A search engine"),
    ('5', "A link from another site"),
    ('6', "From a book"),
    ('7', "Other")
    )

boxes_choices = (
    ("des", "Website Design"),
    ("svr", "Web Server Administration"),
    ("com", "Electronic Commerce"),
    ("mkt", "Web Marketing/Advertising"),
    ("edu", "Web-Related Education")
    )

name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100, required=True)
email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email Address:')
occupations = forms.ChoiceField(choices=occupations_choices, label='What is your occupation?')
howreach = forms.ChoiceField(choices=howreach_choices, label='How did you reach this site?')
# radio buttons 1-5
rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=range(1,6), label='What is your occupation?', widget=forms.RadioSelect)

boxes = forms.ChoiceField(choices=boxes_choices, label='Are you involved in any of the following? (check all that apply):', widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

And I wanted to display it like this:

```
template_values = {
        'url' : url,
        'url_linktext' : url_linktext,
        'userName' : userName,
```

'item1' : SurveyForm()
            }

And I have this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp_*init*_.py", line 515, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\demos\b00213576\main.py", line 144, in get
>       self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.py", line 143, in render
>       return t.render(Context(template_dict))
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.py", line 183, in wrap_render
>       return orig_render(context)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 168, in render
>       return self.nodelist.render(context)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 705, in render
>       bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 718, in render_node
>       return(node.render(context))
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
>       return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 705, in render
>       bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 718, in render_node
>       return(node.render(context))
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 768, in render
>       return self.encode_output(output)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template_*init*_.py", line 757, in encode_output
>       return str(output)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\util.py", line 26, in **str**
>       return self.**unicode**().encode(settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\forms.py", line 73, in **unicode**
>       return self.as_table()
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\forms.py", line 144, in as_table
>       return self._html_output(u'%(label)s%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s', u'%s', '', u'
> %s', False)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\forms.py", line 129, in _html_output
>       output.append(normal_row % {'errors': bf_errors, 'label': label, 'field': unicode(bf), 'help_text': help_text})
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\forms.py", line 232, in **unicode**
>       value = value.**str**()
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\util.py", line 26, in **str**
>       return self.**unicode**().encode(settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\widgets.py", line 246, in **unicode**
>       return u'
>
>   \n%s\n
>
> ' % u'\n'.join([u'
>
> %s
>
> ' % w for w in self])
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\widgets.py", line 238, in **iter**
>       yield RadioInput(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\newforms\widgets.py", line 212, in **init**
>       self.choice_value = smart_unicode(choice[0])
>   TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

Do You have any idea how I can do this validation in different case?

I have tried to do it using this kind of:

```
class ItemUserAnswer(djangoforms.ModelForm):
```

class Meta:
  model = UserAnswer

But I dont know how to add extra labels to this form and it is displayed in one line.
Do You have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot as it making me crazy why it is still not working:/

Answer (score 1):

The builtin method `is_valid()` should validate.
When submitting a form I do it with HTTP POST

```
    def post(self):
    try:
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        if upload_files:
            blob_info = upload_files[0]  
    except:
        self.response.out.write('File not uploaded')        
    try:
        data = AForm(data=self.request.POST)
        if data and data.is_valid():
            # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
            entity = data.save(commit=False)
            entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
            entity.put()
            if upload_files:            
                im = Image(reference=entity) 
                im.primary_image = blob_info.key()
                im.put()
                entity.put()
                self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
        else:
            # Reprint the form
            self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                    '<form method="POST" '
                                    'action="/">'
                                    '<table>')
            self.response.out.write(data)
            self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                    '<input type="submit">'
                                    '</form></body></html>')
    except:
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue

> rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=range(1,6), label='What is your occupation?', widget=forms.RadioSelect)

choices is set to an integer value.

Comment: It should be in the form as the other choice fields are.